# Implementing css behavior attribute in LESS Mixins

Tags: css, less

I've been playing around with LESS for a little bit to see about converting the website I manage at work over.

When I was learning about the `behavior: url(...blah)` ability of css I thought I had read that it was best to use that as little as possible for performance reasons (I now can't find that anywhere so not sure if that's still valid).

So with that assumption in mind I am a little apprehensive about converting that CSS into a LESS Mixin.  Is this truly a performance hit or can I safely do this without being concerned about a slow down of the site's UI?

an example of what I'd be converting...

```
.FullRoundedBorder
{
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    behavior: url(/Content/CSS/PIE/PIE.htc);
}
```

For those that haven't seen it [PIE](http://css3pie.com/about/) is an awesome plugin for rounded border cross browser functionality (mainly it fixes IE 6-8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the 'behavior' property itself is not a major performance concern -- you may have been thinking of 'expression' which is indeed very bad for performance.

However, you do need to examine the performance of the specific .htc that you pull in. Essentially .htc files are pieces of JavaScript that are executed when the CSS selector matches an element. This means that the more elements that are matched by your selector, the more times that script will run.

In the case of a complex script like PIE.htc, it is very easy to use it on too many elements resulting in a noticeable delay while it runs. Like any other script, you need to be deliberate about how widely you apply it, and of course test the performance of your site after applying it.

My experience with PIE.htc is that using it on about 15 elements or fewer is not noticeable, but beyond that you start noticing a delay. There are often things you can do to lessen the impact, such as using [-pie-lazy-init](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-lazy-init).

Comment: Do you happen to know if PIE will run even on browsers where it isn't necessary? (anything besides 6-8 I believe)

Comment: It will add linear gradient support to IE9. It will not affect any other browsers. They ignore the behavior property altogether, and do not even grab the script.

Comment: @zim2411 Thanks I wasn't sure it was ignored like `expression` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PIE will slow down the UI in IE6-8. The more effects you stack on, the greater the impact. It should not affect other browsers.

I used PIE in a (big!) project last year to get some effects in IE6-8, but upon revisiting that project this year I decided to scrap all use of PIE. I found it to be flaky and inconsistent -- it would randomly fail to render a "Pay Now" button for instance. IE users would therefore be randomly incapable of paying their bill. I switched back to Modernizr with an image fallback for < IE 9. The moral of the story is: PIE seems great, but use it sparingly and only for non critical elements. It's difficult to debug when it goes wrong.

You can also easily try it and just disable it if you find your UI is too slow with it. If your mixins are good, it should only be a few lines of code.

Comment: I've never seen any issues with it (personally), but I also don't support ie6 AT ALL it's not a large enough market share to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, we saw problems on IE8 though. Granted, this was a build from last year, they've updated since then.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll look into it a bit more if I have time, but luckily I haven't seen a hit with it yet.  At the moment I'm simply using it to round the top edges of some tabs and `fieldset` elements though!

Answer (score -1):

I've worked extensively with Less. I like how it breaks large CSS into more logical and readable chunks. A few things to consider:

1) Will you be processing the Less server side or client side? I'm more of a proponent of putting fewer load on the UI/Browser because you simply don't have control over what kind of machine, browser the user is running and it adds more points of failure in your UI implementation. Simpler is always better. If your UI is for a small audience then you should see no performance hit. In most cases I will use Less when the plain CSS would be too large to easily maintain and read and thus accept a slight performance hit, especially if the user base is trivial. For high traffic sites, I would probably rewrite or convert back to CSS and publish the straight CSS.

2) Is Less really necessary? Are you loading a bunch of translation code or running an extra process on your server just so you don't have to write a few extra lines of CSS??? This is not justification enough in my Opinion. I often question the use of other "make your life easy" libraries/tools like JQuery, when i see a developer loading an entire library just because they didn't want to write "getElementByID()" pure native JavaScript.

Everything has it's place and it's use in a project/implementation. I suggest making a list of the benefits and then eliminating those that can be readily implemented with native browser features(plain CSS and JS). Smaller and lighter is always better and faster, especially if you're also running on mobile and legacy platforms.

I hope this helped.

Comment: 1) It will be server side 2) Necessary... No, but I like the nesting abilities and since the client side will only see CSS I consider this to be of little consequence.  I also like the built in minification features of dotless (the less framework I'm using).

Comment: The question isn't about using LESS or not using LESS, but about potential performance issues with the extensive use of PIE.

Comment: As @cimmanon correctly points out, this answer seems to go off at a tangent. Maybe you could get it back on track?